# Join table on itself - performance

Tags: mysql, self-join

I would like some help with the following join.
I have one table (with about 20 million rows) that consists of:

**MemberId (Primary Key) | Id (Primary Key) | TransactionDate | Balance**

I would like to get the latest Balance for all the customers in one query.
I know I could do something like this (I just wrote it from my memory). But this way is terribly slow.

```
SELECT * 
FROM money 
WHERE money.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) 
                  FROM money AS m 
                  WHERE m.MemberId = money.MemberId)
```

Are there any other (faster/smarter) options?

Comment: To be sure, the primary key is composite, and the first column is MemberId?

Comment: Umbrella has a good answer, but I would be really interested to find out how MySQL deals with the `IN` operator (replace the first `=`), if you don't mind.

Comment: @Benoit Yes the primary key is composite and the first column is MemberId (It's a MyIsam table)

Comment: @JonathanDickinson It's slow with the IN also

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I saw there are some query optimizer improvements in the [6.0 experimental](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/6.0_Subquery_Optimization_Benchmarks) - in theory (the theory being how MsSQL behaves :)) `IN` should be faster; so keep it mind for when MySQL catches up - because it's the 'right' way to be thinking in SQL terms (think in sets and not rows). SQL gets its bad performance name from people using it with a 'row' mindset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all optimization tutorials and screencasts that I've endured through, joins are always favoured over subqueries. When using a sub-query the sub-query is executed for each comparison, where as with a join only once.

```
SELECT * 
FROM money m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT memberId, MAX(id) AS maxid
    FROM money
    GROUP BY memberId
) mmax ON mmax.maxid = m.id AND mmax.memberId = m.memberId
```

Comment: Really nice solution. It was much much faster than the query I used

Answer (score 2):

JOINing is not the best way to go about this.  Consider using a GROUP BY clause to sift out the last transaction for each member, like this:

<strike>SELECT MemberId, MAX(Id), TransactionDate, Balance FROM money GROUP BY MemberId</strike>

**UPDATE**

as PKK pointed out, balance will be chosen randomly.  It looks like you'll have to perform some sort of join after all.  Consider this option:

```
SELECT MemberId, Id, TransactionDate, Balance FROM money WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT MAX(Id) FROM money GROUP BY MemberId
)
```

Comment: Edited to get the Max Id instead of Date

Comment: TransactionDate and Balance will be chosen randomly. Not according to the MAX(Id)

Comment: This is not correct. You will indeed get the maximum id for each member, but both the TransactionDate and Balance will be chosen completely random between each members records. Writing a query like this is not safe.

Comment: I'm afraid PKK is correct.  I've edited this to give you another option.

Comment: @Umbrella it works with the IN but it is slow (just as with the =). The answer from nikc worked nicely and fast

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to lookup for NULL values in a left join:

```
SELECT m1.*
  FROM money m1
  LEFT JOIN money m2 ON m2.memberId = m1.memberId AND m2.id > m1.id
 WHERE m2.memberId IS NULL
```

But of course [Umbrella's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713527/457352) is better.