# Using MySQL "in" causes loop?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, loops, has-and-belongs-to-many

When I isolate this query:

```
SELECT `Tagged`.`contact_id` 
FROM contacts_tags AS Tagged LEFT JOIN tags AS Tag ON (`Tagged`.`tag_id` = `Tag`.`id`)  
WHERE `Tag`.`id` = 137;
```

i get:

```
+------------+
| contact_id |
+------------+
|       3519 |
|      17080 |
+------------+
```

But when i combine it with a larger query using "IN" I get some sort of recursive loop and my database starts eating up processing power until it times out.

```
SELECT `Contact`.*
FROM `contacts` AS `Contact` 
WHERE `Contact`.`id` in 
(SELECT `Tagged`.`contact_id` 
FROM contacts_tags AS Tagged LEFT JOIN tags AS Tag ON (`Tagged`.`tag_id` = `Tag`.`id`)  
WHERE `Tag`.`id` = 137 );
```

This just keeps running until i reset the server.

But then It works when I list the first query response manually:

```
SELECT `Contact`.*
FROM `contacts` AS `Contact` 
WHERE `Contact`.`id` in 
(3519, 17080);
```

What is the difference?

Comment: SQL doesn't get stuck in a loop, unless you explicitly use loops. If it runs too long, it probably means the query is extremely expensive. How much data do you have in your database that this runs on?

Comment: What indexes do you have in the tables?

Comment: Also, for a performance increase, consider using a JOIN to your subquery, instead of an IN (...).  For example, look at the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713476/join-table-on-itself-performance/8713527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current GA release of MySQL is *really* bad at optimizing subequeries. Chances are that the subquery is being executed for each row in `Contacts`. You can see this if you run `EXPLAIN your_query_here`. You'll like see that the subquery has been tagged `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`.

It's not a great solution, but something like this might work.

```
"SELECT `Contact`.*
FROM `contacts` AS `Contact` 
WHERE `Contact`.`id` in 
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT `Tagged`.`contact_id` 
FROM contacts_tags AS Tagged LEFT JOIN tags AS Tag ON (`Tagged`.`tag_id` = `Tag`.`id`)  
WHERE `Tag`.`id` = 137 ) x);"
```

This should force MySQL to cache the subquery. Alternatively, if you know that query is going to return a small number of values, you might be better off simply performing two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

If one looks at the subquery

```
SELECT ct.contact_id 
FROM contacts_tags AS ct
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON ct.tag_id = t.id
```

Then it does **not restrict** `contact_tags`: delete `LEFT` for a restriction (equi-join).

Rewritten it looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM contacts AS c
JOIN tags AS t ON  c.id = t.contact_id
JOIN contacts_tags AS ct ON ct.tag_id = t.id
WHERE
    t.id = 137
```

or

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contacts AS c
JOIN tags AS t ON  c.id = t.contact_id
WHERE
    t.id = 137
AND
    EXISTS(SELECT *
    FROM contacts_tags AS ct
    WHERE ct.tag_id = 137)
```

**Which is just weird.** It looks like some condition is missing.